# Inspect django model value before saving

Tags: python, django

I have a Sandwich model with a list of Ingredients attribute (a many-to-many relationship so I can see Sandwiches using Ingredients and vice-versa). I also have a field `has_dairy` that I want to set when the model gets saved based on inspecting attributes of the ingredients. Unfortunately, overriding the save method won't cut it, as you can't inspect the value of the many-to-many field without first saving. Else, you get an error.

`ValueError: "<Sandwich: test sandwich>" needs to have a value for field "sandwich" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.`

Ideally, I could save, update `has_dairy`, and save again, but calling `super(Sandwich, self).save(*args, **kwargs)` in the save method twice throws an integrity error, as it's expecting an unsaved state.

How does one accomplish this?

Comment: Set has_dairy early in the form clean method or late in a post save signal.